# How to decrease line space of tRichEdit

Tags: delphi

I use tRichEdit to set line colors. I want to decrease line space like tMemo.

When I input an alphabet manually the line space decreases automatically but when I use tRichEdit.lines.add nothing happens.

If it's not possible are there any substitutes?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. By "input manually", do you mean typing at the keyboard? I just did a quick test app, and I get no difference between adding them via `RichEdit1.Lines.Add` and entering on the keyboard.

Comment: Line spacing has nothing to do with how text is added, whether manually or with `Lines.Add()`. It is related to the font that you have assigned to the RichEdit, or you can use `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` to configure the spacing via the `PARAFORMAT2.dyLineSpacing` structure field.

Comment: @KenWhite yes i typed. i guessed it was because of font or character set but they were same even after that. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can adjust line spacing by sending the `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` via `SendMessage`, setting `PFM_LINESPACING` in the `dwMask` and providing values for the `dyLineSpacing` value (and setting the `bLineSpacingRule` value so that the RichEdit knows how to interpret the former). The code below sets a very tight linespacing in the `TRichEdit` (the lines actually slightly overlap each other):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Para: TParaFormat2;
begin
  Para.cbSize := SizeOf(Para);
  Para.dwMask := PFM_LINESPACING;
  Para.bLineSpacingRule := 4;  // Use exact twips specified
  Para.dyLineSpacing := 120;   // Ridiculously small value
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, LPARAM(@Para));
end;
```

For more information, see the MSDN documentation for [EM_SETPARAFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: i appreciate your kind answer and delicate code. it works well and is helpful.

Comment: thank you so much, I found that in WinWord and WordPad you can get line spacing less than 1 (single line) also with rule 5, RichEdit only with rule 4