# TRichEdit - How to add an empty line with size change?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, richedit, trichedit

I have array of strings and i want to add an empty line of lesser size between some of them.
So i have a code:

```
  const _n=#13#10;
  //...
  r1.Lines.Clear;
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=18;
  r1.SelText:='TEST';
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=6;
  r1.SelText:=_n+'............';
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=18;
  r1.SelText:=_n+'test1';
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=6;
  r1.SelText:=_n+' ';
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=18;
  r1.SelText:=_n+'test2';
```

and size change works for first line (with dots), but line between test1 and test2 has same size as they (18) somehow =\

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some workaround: it's possible to use tab-symbol in place of space.

So the following code works fine:

```
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=18;
  r1.SelText:=_n+'test1';
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=6;
  r1.SelText:=_n+#9; // <- tab here
  r1.SelAttributes.Size:=18;
  r1.SelText:=_n+'test2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting empty lines you could change the line spacing of individual lines by sending EM_SETPARAFORMAT messages to the Richedit. See this question

> [How to decrease line space of tRichEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311125/how-to-decrease-line-space-of-trichedit)

for an example. To increase the line spacing change the value of "Para.dyLineSpacing". Use "500" to get an idea of the effect.

Comment: Well, i don't see how it could be applied to individual lines, and anyways as i said i found workaround with tab-symbol.